# Role Name in view not Matching the RoleID from the UserRole model and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with an MVC template, and have User, Role, and UserRole models and tables.  I am able to add and remove permissions without issue, but when I list the current UserRoles in an index view, the Role name is sequential in the list and not the Name for the Role for that user.

My Controller is very straight-forward

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userroles = db.UserRoles.Include(u => u.Users).Include(u => u.Roles).ToList();
        return View(userroles);
    }
```

And here is where my view falls down

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users.DisplayName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roles.Name)
    </td>
```

The RoleID is correct for the User displayed, but the item.Roles.Name is just whatever the next item is in the Roles table sequentially.  What am I missing here?

Here is the UserRole model if that helps as well:

```
public partial class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    public virtual User Users { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I found that the issue existed in the data tables, where the UserID and RoleId were not associating back to the User and Role tables. Hopefully this helps someone else avoid my mistake.